# Retrieve data from a specific entity in an inheritance relationship in Spring Data Mongo

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have implemented an inheritance relationship using Spring Data MongoDB

I have an abstract entity that contains all the attributes common to all the others.

```
@Document(collection = PersonEntity.COLLECTION_NAME)
public abstract class PersonEntity {

    public final static String COLLECTION_NAME = "persons";

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    @Field("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Field("last_name")
    private String lastName;

    private Integer age;


    public PersonEntity(){}

    @PersistenceConstructor
    public PersonEntity(String firstName, String lastName, Integer age) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }


    public ObjectId getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getFullName(){
        return this.firstName + " - " + this.lastName;
    }

}
```

This entity inherits the entities UserSystemEntity and SonEntity. These have specific **@Field** attributes and do not define the **@Document** annotation. So all documents are stored in the collection of "PERSONS".

To work with these entities I have created the corresponding repositories. Here I put the repository for the entity **SonEntity**.

```
@Repository
public interface SonRepository extends MongoRepository<SonEntity, ObjectId> {
    Iterable<SonEntity> findByParentId(ObjectId id);
    Long countByParentId(ObjectId id);
    Long countByParentIdAndId(ObjectId parentId, ObjectId id);
}
```

The problem I have, is that when I use this repository to obtain a list of entities "SonEntity" by the following method:

```
@Override
    public Page<SonDTO> findPaginated(Pageable pageable) {
        Page<SonEntity> childrenPage = sonRepository.findAll(pageable);
        return childrenPage.map(new Converter<SonEntity, SonDTO>(){
            @Override
            public SonDTO convert(SonEntity sonEntity) {
               return sonEntityMapper.sonEntityToSonDTO(sonEntity);
            }
        });
```

It returns me documents of all entity types (UserSystemEntity, ParentEntity, SonEntity).

How can I configure this correctly to retrieve only the documents of the SonEntity entity?

Thanks in advance.

"SonEntity" Entity code:

```
public final class SonEntity extends PersonEntity {

    @DBRef
    private SchoolEntity school;
    @DBRef
    private ParentEntity parent;

    public SonEntity() {
    }

    @PersistenceConstructor
    public SonEntity(String firstName, String lastName, Integer age, SchoolEntity school, ParentEntity parent) {
        super(firstName, lastName, age);
        this.school = school;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public SchoolEntity getSchool() {
        return school;
    }

    public void setSchool(SchoolEntity school) {
        this.school = school;
    }

    public ParentEntity getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(ParentEntity parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

}
```

"UserSystemEntity" code:

```
public class UserSystemEntity extends PersonEntity {

    @Field("email")
    protected String email;

    @Field("password")
    protected String password;

    @Field("is_locked")
    protected Boolean locked = Boolean.FALSE;

    @Field("last_login_access")
    protected Date lastLoginAccess;

    @DBRef
    protected AuthorityEntity authority;

    public UserSystemEntity() {
    }

    @PersistenceConstructor
    public UserSystemEntity(String firstName, String lastName, Integer age, String email, String password, AuthorityEntity authority) {
        super(firstName, lastName, age);
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Boolean isLocked() {
        return locked;
    }

    public void setLocked(Boolean locked) {
        this.locked = locked;
    }

    public Date getLastLoginAccess() {
        return lastLoginAccess;
    }

    public void setLastLoginAccess(Date lastLoginAccess) {
        this.lastLoginAccess = lastLoginAccess;
    }

    public AuthorityEntity getAuthority() {
        return authority;
    }

    public void setAuthority(AuthorityEntity authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserSystemEntity [email=" + email + ", password=" + password + ", locked=" + locked + ", authority="
                + authority + "]";
    }
}
```

"ParentEntity" code:

```
public final class ParentEntity extends UserSystemEntity {

    public ParentEntity() {
    }

    @PersistenceConstructor
    public ParentEntity(String firstName, String lastName, Integer age, String email, String password,
            AuthorityEntity authority) {
        super(firstName, lastName, age, email, password, authority);
    }

}
```

Here you can verify that when trying to list all entities of type "SonEntity" appear data of other entities. The user "admin" is stored in the DB as a document of type **UserSystemEntity**:

[image: son entities]

The information is stored in MongoDB as follows:

[image: Information on MongoDB]

Comment: Can you post all entities code?

Comment: Of course!!. I've already changed the question. Thank you

Comment: And as I understand you get ClassCastException in your mapper yes?

Comment: No exception occurs. The information is shown in a table with a template in Thymeleaf. And some fields appear empty.

Comment: And you're sure that elements are not of type `SonEntity` ?

Comment: Yes, I added an image with the table I see. User data that is not stored as "SonEntity" type entities is displayed.

Comment: Please also add mongodb rows from database

Comment: Of course, I have already modified the question. Thank you